# .Net Core DenyAnonymousAuthorization Requirement error

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I m getting a 401 error status with this message while trying to retrieve some data from another Net core 5 Web api :

***"Authorization failed. These requirements were not met:DenyAnonymousAuthorizationRequirement: Requires an authenticated user.."***

On the Web api I m using a windows authentification :

> services.AddAuthentication(HttpSysDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

I cannot found many documentation on this kind of authentification, and I don't think that I miss something Any thoughts please ?

Comment: Can you show more details about how to reproduce this issue, I have tried to reproduce your issue, but failed, it works well in my local side.

Answer (score 0):

Try swapping around the calls where it is first setup.

`app.UseAuthentication(); app.UseAuthorization();`

I had the same error where everything else looked fine. Until I swapped these around I kept getting this issue trying to access the endpoint using a token.